# Scoped_lock with repeating arguments

Tags: c++, locking, mutex, deadlock

I use std::scoped_lock to guard pairs of objects in multi-threading environment. But I found that scoped_lock can lead to deadlock (in Visual Studio and gcc) if both its arguments are the same. For example,

```
#include <mutex>

struct S
{
    mutable std::mutex m;
    int v = 0;
    S & operator = ( const S & b )
    {
        std::scoped_lock l( m, b.m );
        v = b.v;
        return * this;
    }
};

int main()
{
    S a;
    a = a; //deadlock here!
}
```

I see that the standard requires “The behavior is undefined if one of MutexTypes is not a recursive mutex and the current thread already owns the corresponding argument in ...”, see
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/scoped_lock/scoped_lock

But formally in my example the mutex is not locked before scoped_locked. So is it expected program behaviour?

Comment: Change `std::mutex` to `std::recursive_mutex`.  Any behavior is expected program behavior when the behavior is **undefined behavior**.

Comment: `std::scoped_lock` effectively calls `std::lock(m,b.m)` which uses " deadlock avoidance algorithm to avoid deadlock." but afaik thats only for cases like calling `std::lock(m,b.m)` in one thread while calling `std::lock(b.m,m)` in another. No matter in what order the locks are acquired, you can't lock a mutex twice. Though on a quick search I didnt find that being mentioned explicitly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phenomena you would really afraid of is "***self deadlock***". It occurs, when 2 conditions are fulfilled simultaneously:

- the **same** thread calls ***repeatedly* mutex.lock()** on the same mutex object,
- and that mutex belongs to non-recursive type, which does not support such recursive locking.

In C++ you have 2 types of mutexes:

- **std::mutex** is non-recursive type - it is quicker and requires less resources,
- **std::recursive_mutex** is recursive type - it is safer but requires more resources.

Now let's apply this knowledge to your specific example:

1. In your case, the obvious way to avoid "***self deadlock***" is to avoid the "***self assignment***". For this purpose simply add the additional check:

   ```
    S & operator = ( const S & b ) 
    {
        if (this != &b) // check it is not self assignment
        {
            std::scoped_lock l( m, b.m );
            v = b.v;
        }
        return * this;
    }
   ```
2. If this is the only usage of your **mutex**, you can be sure that recursive "**self deadlocking**" will never occur. So, this is the best and cheapest solution.
3. If you are going to add other "synchronized" method which calls the current one when mutex is already held by calling thread, then (and only in such case) you really need to replace the **std::mutex** type to be **std::recursive_mutex**.